# Add a leading zero until the number 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of numbers up to the number 10:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I need to put a zero in front of each number except the number 10.

So it looks like this:
01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10

HTML looks like this:

```
<p class=​"number weight-400">​1</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​2​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​3​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​4​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​5​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​6​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​7​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​8​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​9​</p>​
<p class=​"number weight-400">​10​</p>​
```

I have jquery to grab them all but I need to figure out how to add a zero to only the first 9 and not the 10th one:

```
$("p.number").each(function(i, index){
    if (index < 10){

    }
});
```

but my each function grabs all the `<p>` and not the integer inside the p tag.

Comment: It's well worth spending some time skimming through the online [jQuery API reference](http://api.jquery.com/) - the first page gives a summary of all the methods, so you can get a sense of what jQuery can do and what methods you're likely to use often. (`.text()` or `.html()`, for example, let you get or set the text or html contents of an element.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("p.number").text(function(i, val){
    return $.trim(val).length === 1 ? '0' + val : val;
});
```

If you call the [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) on the whole collection the function you supply will be called for each item in your collection - the value you return from the function will be the new text of the current element.

Comment: Well s***! You beat me to it. +1!

Answer (score 5):

Another option, with regex:

```
$('.number').text(function(i, txt) {
  return txt.replace(/^\d$/, '0$&');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/axuyiv/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p.number").each(function(i, elem){
    var numb = parseInt( $(elem).text(), 10 );

    numb = numb < 10 ? '0' + numb : numb;
    $(elem).text(numb);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4r6G/)

Comment: Dont you need `numb= (numb < 10) ?...`

Comment: @Leeish - more specifically: [nope!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Sometimes I dislike javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick dirty way:

```
var num = 2;
num = (num < 10)?("0"+num):num;  //"02"
```

> *<sub>Ha I tricked you. It is even not a dirty code.</sub>*